# Concat String to a number returns zero

Tags: php, mysql, phpactiverecord

I'm having a table whith 'id' as pk of type int.
When I'm doing the folowing mysql query in php activerecord

`Location_cat::find_by_sql("select concat('#',id) as 'id', text FROM location_cat");`

it returns 'id' as 0, instead of '#142'for example.

Does anyone knows this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to overwrite the 'id' field, but this will give you issues. An activerecord object knows it's own primary key (i'd assume the id-field), and uses it for all sorts of stuff. If you try to select something else into that field, this will not work.

For instance, you get the object with id 1. This is renamed to `#1` by you. now AR thinks it is an object with a primary key that is `#1`. Which is not true

Bottomline is, you should not put something else in the `id` field if you want to work with an actual activerecord object.

What you might want to do is just get the data, but on returning the `$object->id` field, you can add the `#`. For instance, make a magic getter for id (I believe AR allows you to name this getId(), but otherwise, fix it in `__get()`.

Answer (score -1):

Lets Cast the id into a string before concatenating

```
SELECT  CONCAT('#', CAST(id AS CHAR(15))) AS nid
FROM   location_cat
```

Comment: I need the column name to be "id" because I dont want to loop the  result once again just to rename the key. Indeed giving it some other name makes it work even without casting it to char. This is a behavior of phpactiverecord, everithing works just fine in mysql. Any ideas?